# Possible to return nested elements from Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Say I have the following structure:

```
{
    site : [
        page1:
        {
            title: "Page One",
            content: "Content for page one"
            subpages : [
                {
                    title: "Subpage one",
                    content: "Content for subpage one"
                },
                {
                    title: "Subpage two",
                    content: "Content for subpage two"
                },
                {
                    title: "Subpage three",
                    content: "Content for subpage three"
                }
            ]
        },

        page2:
        {
        ...
        },

        page3:
        {
        ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve Subpage One's content, i.e. store a large nested structure and retrieve a specific node within that structure based on an xpath-style specifier. I would also like to be able to update that node.

Looking at [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields), I don't think it's possible, but I heard somewhere that it is.

Comment: what do you mean by xpath-style?

Comment: something like `/site/page1/subpages[2]/content` or `site.page1.subpages[2].content`, to be executed as a query

Comment: simple dot notation works, and there is the magic `$` to get matched part but that's it, nothing more complex

Comment: But if I store an entire collection of documents as one large nested structure, for example, can I retrieve a specific document (at an arbitrary nesting level) without having to fetch the entire collection from the database? (I'm not necessarily saying this is a good idea!).

Comment: If it accessible via the dot notation then yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible - the documentation is right.

Answer (score 0):

This any use to you?

```
IN: > thing =  { "foo" : "1", "subthing" : {  "bar" : "2",  "subsubthing" : {  "baz" : "3"  }  } }
OUT: {
 "foo" : "1",
 "subthing" : {  "bar" : "2",  "subsubthing" : {  "baz" : "3"  }  }
 }

IN > thing.foo
OUT: "1"

IN: > thing.subthing
OUT: {
 "bar" : "2",
 "subsubthing" : {  "baz" : "3"  }
 }

IN: > thing.subthing.bar
OUT: "2"

IN: > thing.subthing.subsubthing
OUT: {
 "baz" : "3"
 }

IN: > thing.subthing.subsubthing.baz = "4"
"4"
> thing.subthing.subsubthing.baz
"4"
```